# Count values based on matching words between two tables

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that has product names and values related to them, like this one:

```
+----------------+------------+-------+
|  product_name  | department | value |
+----------------+------------+-------+
| Golden Fish    | Food       |    31 |
| Red Fish       | Food       |    70 |
| Red Socks      | Clothing   |    20 |
| XXL Socks      | Clothing   |    26 |
| Yogurt         | Food       |     9 |
| Protein Yogurt | Food       |     5 |
+----------------+------------+-------+
```

And now, with me having a second dataframe of products, i want to look for every line that has a matching word, and sum up the values.

For example, in this new table of products (not the original one), the values would be:

```
+--------------+----------------------+
| product_name | value (sum involved) |
+--------------+----------------------+
| Cod Fish     | 101 (70+31)          |
| XXL T-Shirt  | 26 (26)              |
| Yogurt       | 14 (9+5)             |
| Red Socks    | 116 (70+20+26)       |
+--------------+----------------------+
```

I have already made a code, which kind of works, but it's way too archaic / slow , and it also has some problems.

My code example:

first_df = First Table example, second_df = Second table example (without the values)

```
def stringCleaning(product_string):
    if '(' in product_string:
        product_string = product_string.replace(r'(', r'\(')
    if ')' in product_string:
        product_string = product_string.replace(r')', r'\)')
    if '[' in product_string:
        product_string = product_string.replace(r'[', r'\[')
    if ']' in product_string:
        product_string = product_string.replace(r']', r'\]')
    return product_string

def countTokens(product_string, count = 0):
    for word in product_string.split(' '):
        if len(word) >= 3:
            count += first_df[first_df['product_name'].str.contains(r'[$ ]'+word+r'[$ ]', regex = True)]['value'].sum()
    return count

second_df['sum_by_tokens'] = second_df['product_name'].apply(lambda x: countTokens(stringCleaning(str(x))))
```

The "Red Socks" line it's one of those situations where i'm getting trouble. Because the function searches for "Socks" and then for "Red", and it will duplicate the value of the line "Red Socks" (20).

Also this code is really slow.
I have a very large dataset, and doing this it will take hours to complete.

I'm looking for a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you have *categories*. If the number of categories is not high and you know all the categories you could make a *category column* and then group by the category.

Comment: Are you suggesting to create one category for each different word? I don't think thats reasonable